# On Excel how do I extract all characters between "x" and "x"

Tags: excel, formulas

In Cell A1 I have a measurements like "22 x 30 x 45" but I want to separate those 3 numbers into 3 separate cells. So I want 22 in B1, 30 in C1 and 45 D1.

I have used this formula to find the first digits `=LEFT(A1,FIND("x",A1)-1)` and I've used this to find the last digits `=Right(A1,FIND("x",A1)-1)` but I can't work out how to find the middle digits?

I need a formula that works with varied lengths so the measurements could be anything from 2 digits to 5 digits

Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `MID` in a similar way that you have used `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to get your middle digits.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("x",A1)+1,FIND("x",A1,FIND("x",A1)+1)-FIND("x",A1)-1)
```

A little repetitive, but it should work.

If you don't want the surrounding spaces, wrap it in a `TRIM` function.

Comment: Thanks mate, A typo on X2 should be A1 but that exactly what I was looking for, I was always going to use trim on them all anyway. Cheers

Comment: Turns out that =Right(A1,FIND("x",A1)-1) didnt actually work for the last digits do you know a bettter formula that will work?

Comment: Use `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("x",A1,FIND("x",A1)+1))` to get the last digits.

Answer (score 1):

or a different approach.
[image]

```
=SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,FIND("x",A1)+1),"")),RIGHT(A1,FIND("x",A1)+1),"")
```

All it really does is substitute out the 22_x_ and the _x_45 using the formula's you used for left/right leaving the 30. (Modified left right to be + 1 instead of -1 to handle the additional characters)

Answer (score 1):

Text to Columns with `x` as the delimiter.

Comment: Cheers mate yeah could of done that but I needed the original information to stay as it was. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Put this in B1 and drag it down and right:

=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" x "&$A1," x ",REPT(" ",99)),COLUMN(A1)*99,99))